# Passing an array to parse through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to pass an array through an AJAX call to the backend, the array gets pushed to the backend, but I'm getting the error "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

This is the

```
 var items = [];
  $("input:checkbox[name='refundcheck']:checked").each(function(){
    let id = $(this).val();
    let item = {
          "id": id,
          "quantity": $('#quantity'+id).val()
    };
    items.push(item);
  });

$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: '{{url("/")}}/products',
          data: {items:items},
          dataType: 'JSON',
          beforeSend:function (){
                 //$("#loadingDiv").show();
          } ,
          success: function( msg ) { 
    }
});
```

This is the console log for that array
[image: This is the console log for that array]

I've tried both of these possibilities

```
$productarraylist = $request->items;

foreach($productarraylist as $item){
    $product= dbtable::find($item->id);
    }
```

AND

```
foreach($productarraylist as $i=> $item){
    $product= dbtable::find($item->id);
    }
```

This is the var_dump result of the array in the backend.

[image]

I tried to JSON.decode the array on the backend, and it says I need to pass a string, not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with arrays and not objects, try this:

```
foreach($productarraylist as $item){
$product= dbtable::find($item['id']);
}
```

Comment: Thank YOU ! How could I possibly parse it as an object? Because the AJAX is pushing it as a JSON so why am I not able to convert it to an object?